# Joomla 3.3.6 - Server not Found for Some but not others

Tags: joomla

We have three users setup with Admin Panel access. 2 of them are not experiencing any issues while one users is getting "server not found" when they try to pull up the admin login screen. I haven't been able to replicate it, but unfortunately it's a client who isn't very tech savvy. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried creating a new account with the same credentials and admin access level to see if the issue still occurs? I assume you don't have any additional backend security such as IP based access or security keys in the URL

Comment: No I haven't - I can try that now.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a Joomla issue. Try another browser, another computer, another network...

Comment: Also, may I suggest you change the password for the account that doesn't work, then trying logging in yourself and if this works, ask your client to login with the same details. If they get the same error, then it will most likely be an issue on their side. Possible network firewall blocking the site or something along those lines

Comment: Perfect - yes I was able to login with their credentials without a problem.